# Erro com o & dentro da query mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Colegas.

Tenho uma tabela que dentro do campo **Dias** traz: **Segunda & Terça**

Porém ao dar query dentro do PHP, não retorna nada, mesmo a query estando correta:

```
   $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM semana WHERE Dias = 'Segundas & Terças'");
```

Quando jogamos diretamente dentro do Mysql, retorna o resultado, mas dentro do PHP não. Acredito que o problema esteja no **&**  Particularmente nunca passei por isso. Alguém saberia como resolver?

Comment: $dias = "Segundas & Terças"; mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM semana WHERE Dias = '".$dias."'"); tente dessa forma

Comment: Qual `charset` do DB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$Dias = "Segundas & Terças";
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM semana WHERE Dias = '".$Dias."'");
```

Passando a variável antes.

Comment: obrigado André.....

Comment: Por nada, só marca minha resposta como certa, por gentileza.

Answer (score 4):

Fox, para evitar muitas intervenções no seu código, recomendo que use a função like:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM semana WHERE Dias LIKE 'Segundas%Terças'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Existem duas formas **CORRETAS** de resolver isso.

1) Escapando **`(\)`** o caracter especial.

`$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM semana WHERE Dias = 'Segundas \& Terças'");`

2) Usando a **[mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)**:

`$dias = mysqli_real_escape_string("Segundas & Terças");
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM semana WHERE Dias = '{$dias}'");`